# Eliminate holes in mesh for stl files

Tags: sculpting

Being a hack while sculpting I end up with multiple holes in the mesh. Many can't be seen and this causes problems when I use the STL file to cnc machine the object. Is there a simple way to correct this and create an even surface without holes?

Comment: There is a function for this, called: "Fill Holes", it can fill every hole which have less then 100 sides. Or you can find holes by: Select>>Select Loops>>Select Boundary Loop. (Both in Edit Mode and select everything before use them).

Comment: also the new remeshers in 2.81 can help to fill the holes